# Converting individual files to arc?

Tags: xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.3

I've seen lots of info about converting a whole project to arc and then using flags to tell Xcode which ones not to convert.

What about converting only individual files to arc? I tried it, and it runs fine. Can I do that? I'm kind of worried that since the whole project isn't converted to arc if I convert things here and there they'll cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. However, you need to tell the compiler which files are not ARC. This you can do in your project settings. Go to `your project` > `Select the target of the app in question` > `Build Phases`. Now drop down the "Compile Sources" and select the files you wish not to compile with ARC, press ENTER and a little popup box will appear. Here you can write `-fno-objc-arc`. Press `Done` and you are done.

When compiling, it will try to add automated reference counting to the files which do not have the `-fno-objc-arc` flag. Very usefull when using non-arc libs such as ASIHTTPRequest or MBProgressHud (and others).

Comment: How can you tell that it is trying to use ARC for the other files? It seems to remember which files it has converted to ARC and which ones it hasn't.

Comment: And what if you're using several libraries that can't use ARC? There are lots of files to change, do you have to set the flags individually for all of them, or is there a better way?

Comment: It is a flag set to the compiler in your project settings called `Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting`.

Comment: Yes, if you have several libs, then you should select the .m files for those libs in the `Build Phase` tab's `Compile Sources` and add this flag to them. This is due to that the projects settings are set to use ARC, which these files don't. So these file should be excluded from ARC by the compiler.

Comment: I already know about this flag. I've used it before. But what if you have to set this flag for 100 files. Do you have to do it individually for each one, or can you select them all at once and set the flag?

Comment: Like I wrote above, `... and select the files you wish not to compile with ARC, press ENTER ...`. So Yes, you can select multiple files and then press the ENTER key on your keyboard to add the flag to all these files at once.

Comment: What if I only selected one file to convert to ARC? How do you know that XCode is using ARC for all the other files that weren't selected?

Comment: You cannot select one file. Either your project has the use arc flag, or it hasn't. The only thing you can do is to select files NOT to use ARC.

Comment: Go to edit->refactor->convert to ARC, and you'll see a list of directories. Those can be opened to show individual files. Then you can select individual files to convert.

Comment: Yes, there you can convert files to ARC. But that is not the answer to your question. You are asking how you can tell the project to use only certain files as ARC files.

Answer (score 1):

To tell only certain file is ARC use flag:

```
-fobjc-arc
```